# Colormap on barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm making a barplot with matplotlib, this is what i got:

```
#Plotando as descobertas acima e mostrando a média de 1 com uma linha branca.
plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))
ax11 = sns.barplot(x=top_atores['VAC'], y=top_atores['Nome Ator'])
plt.axvline(1, ls='-', color='white', linewidth=3)
plt.xlabel('VAC', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Ator', fontsize=12)
plt.title('VAC por Ator Comparado à Média', fontsize=14)
plt.savefig('VACAtor');
```

The result:
[barplotrainbow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7cPa.png)

I wanted to use a colormap palette, specifically the 'magma' one, but don't know how to put it in the code.

Comment: What about it is not working?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example with a contrived or simplified dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I only had to put the palette on line 3! Now it's working.

````
plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))
ax11 = sns.barplot(x=top_atores['VAC'], y=top_atores['Nome Ator'], palette='magma')
plt.axvline(1, ls='-', color='white', linewidth=3)
cmap = plt.cm.autumn
plt.xlabel('VAC', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Ator', fontsize=12)
plt.title('VAC por Ator Comparado à Média', fontsize=14)
plt.savefig('VACAtor');```
````

Comment: Sounds like a typo, so this question can probably be deleted.